# registry.npmjs.org request time out

Tags: npm, time, request, out

all of npm install package is return ETIMEOUT

i checked by command

```
tracert registry.npmjs.org

Tracing route to registry.npmjs.org [104.16.27.35]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  10.192.54.254
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.192.54.12
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.250.5
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  203.147.57.179
  5     4 ms     4 ms     4 ms  10.210.20.53
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  10.210.20.2
  8     7 ms     7 ms     7 ms  203.147.29.244
  9     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  166.84.50.182.static-corp.jastel.co.th [182.50.84.166]
 10    33 ms    32 ms    33 ms  90.84.50.182.iig-ne1-sg1.jastel.co.th [182.50.84.90]
 11    83 ms    94 ms   104 ms  13335.sgw.equinix.com [27.111.228.132]
 12    31 ms    31 ms    32 ms  104.16.27.35

Trace complete.

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ETickets_DEV>npm install polyfill-library --save  --prefer-offline --no-audit
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/lazystream failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

hop no. 6 is "Request timed out" all time

i think it make npm installion is failed.

may i used some npm option for skipt ETIMEOUT error?

Comment: Welcome to [StackOverflow.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com)! Your question is lacking of details: [we are simply unable to help you in its current state...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Edit the answer to specify *at least*: What have you tried so far? What technologies/languages are you using? Why it "does not work"? What are you trying to accomplish? What do you get *precisely*?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?